# Disable popup ad with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup banner on a site and I want to disable it with javascript. I am looking for methods other then actually removing it from the source code.

Is there a way to disable it with javascript or php/html? The code looks like this:

```
<noscript><a href='adURL'><img src='adIMG'/></a></noscript>
```

Comment: I'd venture to guess that by using that free site that you're not allowed to interfere with the ads.

Comment: How is a noscript tag a pop up ad?

Comment: A `noscript` will only run if you've disabled JavaScript. So you can't disable it using JavaScript if it's being shown.

Comment: You could try paying for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use jquery:

```
$("noscript").hide();
```

Comment: And if the noscript tag is showing, how is JavaScript going to run to hide it? lol

Comment: @epascarello It's like magic!!

Comment: Y'all posting in troll thread. This must be trolling.

Comment: Looks like there might be some other code triggering the popup. Any idea how to disable all javascript on that page? BTW this is not trolling I'm just new to JS.